# Having difficulty with unit testing MobX observer components with multiple stores injected

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme, mobx

My understanding with MobX inject decorator is that, with Enzyme, I should be able to simply initialize a store in my unit test and then pass as a prop to the component I'm mounting. [src: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-test-react-and-mobx-with-jest and scroll to the Integration Tests section.] But I keep getting the Store not Available! error. This tends to be an issue particularly if I am injecting multiple stores.

So in my component:

```
export default inject('errorStore', 'someOtherStore', 'andTheThirdStore')(observer(MyComponent));
```

My test should look like this.

```
import errorStore from './stores/errorStore';
import someOtherStore from './stores/someOtherStore';
import andTheThirdStore from './stores/andTheThirdStore';
import Component from './components/Component';

describe('My Component', () => {
  someOtherStore.initializeWithData('./examples','TEST-123-45678-90', 'USERID');
  andTheThirdStore.initialize();
  const storeProp = { errorStore, someOtherStore, andTheThirdStore };

  beforeEach(() => {
      const wrapper = mount(<Component {...storeProp} />
  }

  it ('does all the things', () => {...});
```

Do I need some other sort of provider here or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see your setup is correct. Do you have a reproducible setup? Note that you can also mount the original component directly by using `wrappedComponent` see also the example in [this issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/176)

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to get this test working with Typescript, but Typescript has no notice of wrappedComponent, any pointers how to fix this? https://1drv.ms/i/s!Alugdb3djzvtiYJPl_tM9nZ6qyS9Jw

Comment: will add the typings to the next version of the package. Any cast should do until then

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyComponent`:

```
export default inject('errorStore', 'someOtherStore', 'andTheThirdStore')(observer(MyComponent));
```

add another line below `export default`:

```
export const  undecorated = MyComponent
```

In your testCase `import {undecorated as MyComponent} from './MyComponent'`

and regarding your stores you need not initialize when you are doing pure unit testing create sample store objects .

In the above example:

```
create const errorStore={}.
```

And one more thing use `shallow` instead of `mount` if you are unit testing.